# How to check an output DbParameter for null value?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm using `System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync` to call an Oracle stored procedure that has one output parameter `o_err_msg` which (you guessed it) is a VARCHAR2 error message when an exception occurs or null when the procedure succeeds. So, after calling `ExecuteNonQueryAsync, I'm trying to check if that parameter is null, to see if there was an error or not. But can't find a way to actually do it.

I've tried comparing (through both the `==` operator and the `Equals` method) the `Value` property of the parameter to null, to `DBNull.Value` and calling `System.Convert.IsDBNull` on it. All of these return null. I've even tried converting it to string (either through the `ToString` method or `System.Convert.ToString`) and then calling `string.IsNullOrEmpty`, but the resulting string is `"null"`.

The code I'm running is somewhat similar to this:

```
DbCommand cmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "PCKG_FOO.PROC_BAR";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("o_err_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000, "", ParameterDirection.Output));

await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

if (cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value != null)
    throw new InvalidOperationException(cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value.ToString());
```

Even though, in this example, I'm initializing the parameters as `OracleParameter`, in my code I only have `DbParameter` accessible and I'd prefer if I didn't have to cast it to `OracleParameter` or anything Oracle-specific.

Is there any way I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well one way to troubleshoot this is to debug a call that you know will output null and check what the value in the parameter is. This should give you an indication of what to compare to at run time

Comment: does `if (cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value is DBNull)` work? ADO.NET uses a placeholder for database `null`, i.e. `DBNull.Value`

Comment: @Nkosi Thanks for the advice! That's how I've trying to do it, though. Adding a Watch for the `Value` property of the parameter results in:
`cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value {null} object {Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleString}`

Comment: @MarcGravell It doesn't work. I've tried both `cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value is DBNull` and `cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"] is DBNull` but both return `false`

Comment: @LuisCosta I wonder... is this one of those "Oracle has no concept of a null string" things?

Comment: use `DBNull.Value` to refer exact value of dbnull @LuisCosta

Comment: @BlackHole If you mean `cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value != DBNull.Value`, I've already tried that.

Comment: @MarcGravell Not sure... ButI really hope not!

Comment: Try `!DBNull.Value.Equals(cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value)`

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem today, the fowling code should be a workarround.

```
OracleParameter out1 = new OracleParameter("out1", OracleDbType.Varchar2, ParameterDirection.Output);
                out1.Size = 1000;
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleString out1Value = (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Types.OracleString)out1.Value;
if (!out1Value.IsNull)
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, the out paramater was returning a `{null}` value, it seems that it isn't the same as `null` from C#.

I fixed it by casting the out parameter value to `OracleString`. Something like this:

```
if ((OracleString)cmd.Parameters["o_err_msg"].Value != null)
```